# could not find driver - PHP Y ORACLE

Tags: php, oracle

Estoy empezando con ORACLE 21c Express Edition y estoy intentando crear una base de datos y conectarla a PHP. He estado buscando en algunos videos y paginas para realizar la conexión y hasta ahora no lo he logrado ya que tengo el error ***could not find driver*** al cargar mi pagina index.php que estoy ocupando como prueba.
Agradecería que alguien me pueda orientar para resolver que me falta o que estoy haciendo mal.

Mi código php para la conexión es el siguiente:

```
<?php 

define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('PORT', 1521);
define('NAME', 'prueba');
define('USER', 'SYSTEM');
define('PASS', 'root');

$bd_setting = "
    (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = 
        (PROTOCOL = TCP)
        (HOST = ".HOST.")
        (PORT = ".PORT.")
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
        (SERVER = DEDICATED)
        (SERVICE_NAME = ".NAME.")
    )
)
";

try
{
    $bd = new PDO('oci:dbname='.$bd_setting, USER, PASS);
    $bd->setAttibute(PDO::ATTR_CASE, PDO::CASE_LOWER);
    $bd->setAttibute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo 'CONEXION EXITOSA';
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo "ERROR DE CONEXION:".$e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo instalaste [*OCI8*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/oci8.installation.php)?

Comment: Solo descargue la aplicación ORACLE 21c Express Edition desde la pagina y ejecute el setup, posteriormente ejecute SQL Developer, solo eso instale

Comment: No se si te refieres a eso???

Comment: ¿Versión de PHP? ¿Versión de SO donde está ejecutando el scrip?

Comment: PHP 8.1.4, mi sistema operativo es Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el módulo OCI no se conecta directamente a la base de Oracle, necesita un intermediario llamado Oracle Instant Client.

Descarga Oracle Instant Client de la misma arquitectura de tu php (x64 o x32) de la página de Oracle. El *Basic Package* sirve:

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html

(*) Verificar que cumples los requisitos, al menos la última versión pide W8 o superior y VCredist 2017 o superior.

Luego descompríme el cliente (usualmente en la raíz) y el directorio donde quedó, por ejemplo `C:\instantclient_21_8`, debes [agregarlo a la variable de entorno PATH](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+add+to+PATH).

Finalmente habilitar `extension=pdo_oci` en php.ini. Como estás usando PDO no creo que sea necesaria la `extension=oci8_19`, pero a tener en cuenta por si acaso.

Comment: Instale Instant Cliente Oracle en la version 21.8 y también Visual Studio, agregue la ruta al PATH y modifique el PHP.ini. Pero sigo con el mismo error.

Comment: Ejecute SQLPLUS en cmd y logro ingresar a la base de datos sin problemas, pero desde PHP aun no puedo

Comment: Logré quitar el error, pero ahora me muestra lo siguiente: SQLSTATE[HY000]: pdo_oci_handle_factory: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor (ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:778)

Comment: Como tenia un problema con el servicio, encontre la siguiente QUERY para consultar mi servicio correcto: select value from v$parameter where name='service_names';

Comment: Después de eso actualice el nombre del servicio en NAME y funcionó. Muchas gracias.